# Optimize code to check a Data Validation cell to pick another cell

Tags: data-validation, conditional-statements

I have cell E2 that contains a Data Validation group: "online", "article", "journal", "proceedings" and "magazine". I am populating cell K2 with a formula that is based on E2's entry. If I select an option for example "article", cell K2 will pick cell P2. Here is the logic that I used in cell K2:

Code:

```
=IF(G2="ONLINE",O2,IF(G2="article",P2,(IF(G2="journal",Q2,IF(G2="proceedings",R2,IF(G2="magazine",S2,T2))))))
```

This code works but I was wondering if there is a simpler solution to minimize this cell code?

Thanks!

Comment: What program  are you talking about?

Comment: Microsoft excel....sorry for omitting that minor detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(O2:T2,MATCH(E2,{"online","article","journal","proceedings","magazine"},0))
```